# GCHandler.cs Error Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Bom dia,

Estou debugando o meu projeto e durante a execução do mesmo me deparo com o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém por acaso já lidou com este problema e pode me ajudar a soluciona-lo?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, solucionei da seguinte forma:

Primeiro baixei o projeto da dll "mscorlib" no seguinte link =

> https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/gchandle.cs

Em seguida onde está escrito na imagem da pergunta "Procurar e localizar gchandle.cs" eu cliquei e fui diretamente na pasta do download do projeto e referenciei a classe.

Funcionou assim para mim, mas ainda não identifiquei o que ocorreu para gerar o problema.

Comment: Você solucionou o problema no Visual Studio ou o que gerava o erro na sua aplicação?

Comment: O que gerava o erro. Aparentemente o meu Visual Studio não está referenciando corretamente a dll mscorlib.
Estou tendo que referenciar manualmente.

Comment: Acho difícil que o visual studio não esteja encontrando a mscorlib, seria o caso de reinstalar, essa requisição do fonte da mscorlib.dll não por que você está tentando debugar um método da classe GCHandle ??